# Looking for a term to describe looking back to a certain point in time

Tags: terminology, technical

I work on designing an application which will enable the user to post "Stories" (diary entries) for parents for their kids. The application has a feature which lets the parent post a story that dates back in time, like if you now in November post the photos from your summer trip to Paris and want to date that entry to July when the trip actually was. later looking at the diary entries for a child you can then "follow" the added time stamp link for those types of stories to see the entry in the context of other entries in that region of time.

I'm wondering if I can find a good recognizable and catchy term to describe this feature (chronological stamp of a post). Initially I've called it "Time jumps", so that an entry can be "Time jumped" and a user can "Time jump" to see entries in the same chronological context.

However a senior designer was not sure about "Time jump" being a good term. So therefore I want to see with you fine people here if you can think of any term that could be a good candidate for describing the semantics of such a feature.

I post this here since I feel it has more to do with terminology and use of the English language rather than user experience which is why I've chosen not to post this on [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are you asking for a word saying "looking back in time" like your title suggests or for one saying "chronological stamp of a post" like your explanation suggests?

Comment: ... Excellent point.

Comment: @skymninge Sorry, it should actually suggest both cases. When one creates a post one can choose to Time stamp it to a date back in time. Looking at the feed of posts one can then choose to see the feed sorted after latest added posts (any manual time stamp of a post is disregarded in the ordering) and one can choose to see the posts sorted on time of entry OR manual Time stamp (so if a post has a manual time stamp this will rule over the generated time stamp at creation). One can also choose to see the feed from a certain point in time, inputting a date and jump to the posts around that time.

Comment: The term I'm looking for should be applicable for all these use cases, which I initially though "Time jump" could be.

Comment: I guess in this case you should rethink the necessity of giving multiple quite different actions the same name. For adding a time to a post, "time stamp" is perfectly find. For looking for time stamped posts from the past, retrospection would be. For sorting, it is "sort by time stamp" again.

Comment: @skymninge Thanks. I see what you mean. And I know that for instant discoverability using a more descriptive term would be preferable. However, this won't be a one-time-use or a walk-up-to system, but would rather hopefully infuse a continuous usage. Therefore I'd be willing to refrain from description in order to formulate something that is more "catchy". For example, you don't "Tweet it yourself", you "Retweet".

Comment: Backdate comes to mind

Comment: what about a `Flashback`?

Comment: @Adsy that's a good suggestion. Unfortunately the term "Flashback" is hijacked by a discussion forum site of a very questionable nature in one of the markets of the app. :)

Comment: This is known as "Twenty-twenty hindsight".  Which will have a whole new meaning come January 1st.

Answer (score 1):

A theoretically matching term would be [retrospection](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrospection), although I am not sure it is good to use in that context as it is very abstract and not what a child would call the "time jump".

Comment: This isn't too bad, it's not one that has crossed my mind anyway. Something to work with perhaps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Catchy you say?

A brazen suggestion, if you would allow:

If I were a client, what would really sell it for me, especially at a younger age, would be to be able to go on a **chrono-trip/tour** through your app.

Comment: haha! You get an A for effort! However, since "chrono" is quite similar to "chronic" (slang for high quality cannabis) together with the DASH "trip", I think we'll have to pass. :)
But you did give us a laugh, so I'll +1 you for that.

Comment: Thank _you_ for expanding my slang dictionary :) . Never knew "chronic" could be used in that context. I can see how that can be ambiguous when combined with the "trip" part. The game is still on then.

Answer (score 1):

*[Vintage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vintage#Noun)* (“The year or place in which something is produced”) is a possibility.

Combining words with *mark*, *marker*, or *stamp* will lend specificity, as in eg *[datestamp](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/datestamp#Noun)* or *[timestamp](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/timestamp#Noun)* (“The date and time at which an event occurred, often included in a log to track the sequence of events”), *vintage mark*, *vintage marker*, *whenmark*.

Answer (score 1):

***Reflect***

As in "reflecting on past experiences".

Answer (score 0):

I think ***reminiscence*** perfectly fits:

> Reminiscence is the act of recollecting past experiences or events, such as when a person shares his personal stories with others or allows other people to live vicariously through stories of family, friends, and acquaintances while gaining an authentic meaningful relationship with a person.
>
> <sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reminiscence</sub>